# store `lbound:ubound` index notation in a variable pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I didn't know how to look for this on SO so other questions might already exist.

I am trying to do

```py
idx = lbound:ubound
df = df.loc[idx]
```

Python does not like the `:` notation.

How should I replace it ?

EDIT : I know I can use `lbound:ubound` directly in `pandas`. The point of the question is to have that notation in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to process integer index, you can use range. If you want to use the method whatever the index type, the bullet proof way is to build an index:

```
idx = df.loc[lbound:ubound].index.unique()
```

You can then safely use:

```
df.loc[idx]
```

---

An alternate method is to store the bounds in a tuple, but the syntax may not be what you want:

```
idx = (lbound, ubound)
df.loc[idx[0]:idx[1]]
```

Comment: idx = df.loc[lbound:ubound].index.unique() ? Otherwise you might end up with tons of duplicates no ?

Comment: Have you assumed that the index was unique for your answer ?

Comment: @Chapo: Thank you for noticing! I am used to databases and often assume that the (primary) index is unique, while Pandas does not require it... I have just approved your edit.

Comment: I was forced to notice when I overwhelmed my RAM due to the duplicates :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
df = df.loc[lbound:ubound]
```

Or:

```
idx = range(lbound, ubound) # or slice() depending on context

df = df.loc[idx]
```

Comment: that's the whole point of the question. I know I can use it in pandas, I'm trying to have it in a variable.

Comment: Then you can use `range`.

Comment: My uinderstanding was the `:` notation would work on strings as well. Am I mistaken ?

Comment: Then I guess you can use `slice` instead.